# Getting channels and looping through them discord.net

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I am trying to create a commands using discord.net that will get a guild by id and then loop through the channels roles and users allowing me to list the names or permission each role or channel has. However, I've run into a few issues. The way I am currently getting my guild is using

`var guild = BotStuff._client.GetGuild(Global.guildid);`

After I get the guild I was able to get the number of channels, roles, or users using

`var channels = guild.Channels;`

and then

`Console.WriteLine(channles.Count);`

However, my main issue is that I want to be able to loop through the channels or roles and change the permissions or log the name of them, but I am unsure of how to accomplish this. I wasn't able to find documentation for this. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It's a collection, just  use `ForEach`

Answer (score 0):

I'll provide you with some examples that would already work with your current variables.

You need to gather the current channels in a guild, however since a Category is still considered a channel, you need to filter it out using the `Where` method in LINQ. This way, we will only have text and voice channels in our enumerable, which we then just loop through using the `foreach` keyword.

In the code examples below, you can modify the channel (name, positon, category) and add the permissions for both users and roles as you wanted.

In case you simply want to type their names into the console, just display the `Name` property in the foreach:
`Console.WriteLine(channel.Name)`

Change the name of each channel in a guild:

```cs
            var guild = BotStuff._client.GetGuild(Global.guildid);

            var channels = guild.Channels.Where(x => !(x is ICategoryChannel));

            foreach (var channel in channels)
            {
                await channel.ModifyAsync(x =>
                {
                    x.Name = "new name";
                });
            }
```

Add a permission overwrite for a user:

```
            var guild = BotStuff._client.GetGuild(Global.guildid);

            var channels = guild.Channels.Where(x => !(x is ICategoryChannel));

            foreach (var channel in channels)
            {
                var guilduser = guild.GetUser(554240045800882181);
                await channel.AddPermissionOverwriteAsync(guilduser, new OverwritePermissions(sendMessages: PermValue.Allow, manageChannel: PermValue.Allow));
            }
```

This way we will let the user of ID 554240045800882181 send messages and manage the channel. You are able to choose between `Allow`, `Inherit`, `Deny`.

The permission adding method is overloaded and also accepts a role as an argument, so with a small modification we can change the channel permissions for a whole group of people.

```cs
                var guildrole = guild.GetRole(202853174959144960);
                await channel.AddPermissionOverwriteAsync(guildrole, new OverwritePermissions(manageMessages: PermValue.Allow, attachFiles: PermValue.Allow));
```

The IDs/variables used are just examples, you should understand and modify the code before using it.

Answer (score 0):

For listing channel : (with a bot, else just replace `Context.Guild.Channel` per u'r getguild variable)

```
            foreach (var channel in Context.Guild.Channels)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(channel.Name);
            }
```